# Timestamp for the API request

Tags: python, json, api, timestamp

I am asking if I can link an API request with a timestamp that it sent so I can sort them later because I am sending them concurrently and sometimes they come out of order.

here is my code and I am appending the results I wounder if I can use some function or method to add a timestamp

```
def get_details(lat, lon):
try:
    time.sleep(1)
    url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+ str(lat) + ',' + str(lon)+'&key='+ API_KEY
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(response.text)
    print("/n",response.text)
    ids.append(data['results'][0]['place_id'])
```

Comment: I dont know your code, but why do you need to sort them by the time they finish? They are only dependant on lat and lon positions? Why don't you make ids a dictionary and do `ids[lat][lon] = data['results'][0]['place_id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally servers provide *their* current time in response header Date for example

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://www.example.com")
print(r.headers["Date"])
```

has given output

```
Mon, 01 Aug 2022 07:24:16 GMT
```

format used is compliant with RFC822, you can parse it as follows

```
from email.utils import parsedate_to_datetime
dt = parsedate_to_datetime(r.headers["Date"])
print(dt)
```

output

```
2022-08-01 07:24:16+00:00
```